# Is it a good idea to define variable names with utf-8 characters?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, language-agnostic, coding-style

Of course this question is only relevant to programming languages that allow utf-8 characters in variable names (eg. python3, golang...)

When I need to write some code from scientific papers, I have the temptation to write that kind of code :

```
θ = 1.
```

When a lot of variable are involved, I think that this code might be clearer and easier to read because the variable has the same name in the code and in the paper. Of course it is much harder to write because the character is not on the keyboard.

What do you think of that idea? What would be your reaction if you were reading that code?

Comment: Which language would accept that character as a variable name? Most have some restrictions on what's valid.

Comment: Especially not θ (GREEK SMALL LETTER THETA), which is easily confusable with 0 (DIGIT ZERO).

Comment: [And this is why it's an especially bad idea.](http://labs.spotify.com/2013/06/18/creative-usernames/)

Comment: Strongly depends on context. I agree that in scientific contexts it makes a lot of sense to use Greek letters, rather than spelling them out (`theta = 0`, etc.). It's easier to compare the written equation to your implementations that way; it actually makes things *less* error prone. Plus, whoever decided that an alphabet in common use may not be used in computing contexts? Seems rather racist to me...It'll have its share of problems of course, which will undoubtedly be more numerous than when restricting yourself to ASCII, but iff used sparingly and with care, sure why not.

Comment: @H2CO3 how relevant is that to naming variables in source code?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Huh, how **isn't** it, rather? The problem is common - different characters, same characters, similar characters, etc. Source code can be modified in a malicious way as well, and Unicode makes that fact easy to hide.

Comment: Clearly you did not understand the issue at hand there: broken normalisation routine. The issue was in the code not in the input. If you want to say "don't do this with buggy implementations" sure.  Otherwise I don't see any relevance

Comment: @H2CO3 Actually, if you are using such a buggy implementation, you already lost. No such discipline will save you from "malicious code changes". The fact that your silly discipline prevents you from using these characters won't prevent that mythical someone that wants to modify code in a malicious way at all. That is, unless you want to ban almost all characters out there, even B, I, G, etc. Note how in the article you linked (did you read it?) those are the characters involved in the "problem", not anything like θ!

Answer (score 3):

I believe if the utf-8 characters works fine in variable names, then if using variable names with utf-8 characters can improve the readability of the program, just use it.